# Validation issue with Joi when using conditional logic in Node.js

Tags: node.js, joi

I am encountering an issue with validation using Joi, when implementing conditional logic for validating specific fields based on the value of another field.

I have a schema where I need to validate an object containing config data. One of the fields in the config data is cycleType, which can have three possible values: 'Daily', 'Weekly', or 'Monthly'. Depending on the value of cycleType, different fields in the cycleInfo and dueScheduleInfo objects should be required or forbidden.

Here is an example of the schema and the code I am using for validation:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const settlementCycle_configValidation = {
  cycleType: Joi.string().required().valid('Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'),
  cycleInfo: Joi.object().keys({

    time: Joi.object().keys({
      hour: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(23),
      minutes: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(59)
    }),
    day: Joi.string().valid(
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday'
    ).when('cycleType', {
      is: 'Weekly',
      then: Joi.required(),
      otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    }), // Required if 'Weekly'
    date: Joi.number().integer().max(28).min(1), // Required if 'Monthly'
  }),
  dueScheduleInfo: Joi.object().keys({
    time: Joi.object().keys({
      hour: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(23),
      minutes: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(59) 
    }),
    day: Joi.string().valid(
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday'
    ).when('cycleType', {
      is: 'Weekly',
      then: Joi.required(),
      otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    }), // Required if 'Weekly'
    date: Joi.number().integer().max(28).min(1), // Required if 'Monthly'
  }),
  operatorDueDay1: Joi.date().utc().format('YYYY/MM/DD')
};
```

I have tried using the Joi.when method to conditionally validate the fields, but I am experiencing issues with the validation logic. Specifically, when the cycleType is set to 'Weekly', the day field in both cycleInfo and dueScheduleInfo should be required, but I'm getting validation errors stating that the day field is not allowed. Same for the cycleType Monthly.
Example object I am trying to send -

```
"configData":{
        "cycleType": "Weekly",
        "cycleInfo": {
            "time": {
                "hour": 2,
                "minutes": 0
            },
            "day": "Monday"
        },
        "dueScheduleInfo": {
            "time": {
                "hour": 16,
                "minutes": 0
            },
             "day": "Monday"
        },
        "operatorDueDay1":"2023/04/01"
    }
```

```
"configData":{
        "cycleType": "Monthly",
        "cycleInfo": {
            "time": {
                "hour": 2,
                "minutes": 0
            },
            "date": 21
        },
        "dueScheduleInfo": {
            "time": {
                "hour": 16,
                "minutes": 0
            },
            "date": 21
        },
        "operatorDueDay1":"2023/04/01"
    }
```